# Configuração Persisisntece.xml com datasource Glassfish

Tags: java, jpa, firebird, glassfish

Pessoal seguinte eu fiz 2 datasources do glassfish!!!!
Onde o primeiro é um banco de dados fixo!!!
Segue imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse datasource esta funcionando correto !!!

O meu segundo eu não passo a propriedade Database porque essa propriedade vem do meu primeiro datasource, ou seja, eu pego o caminho e o ip do servidor do primeiro data datasource!!

Segue imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então eu passo a propriedade na minha classe de Conexao quando vou criar o EMF

Segue imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que ele não pega a propriedade do banco de dados e dá o seguinte erro:
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Database was not specified. Cannot provide connections.

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Pesquise sobre Multitenancy.
O Hibernate e o EclipseLink trazem suporte.
acredito que lhe ajudará

Comment: o Problema do Multitenacy é q eu tenho q ter todos os endereços dos banco de dados que eu tenho , e essa informação eu tenho dentro de um banco de dados chamado Gestor !!! por isso eu faco a conexao no Gestor, pego os dados do banco de dados do cliente , como ip do sv e local , ai faco a conexao !!!